# Java TCP Simple Webserver Problems with response codes (homework)

Tags: java, http, tcp, webserver

This is an assignment for a course we are having and i need some help.

I am having problems for example, trying to request a file that does not exist, it works that a 404 file not found page comes up, but when i look in the web tool for Safari i can see that the response code is 200, OK, which is definialty wrong, it should be the code that is the error.

But why i don't see, i send the error code header when a error occurs, but it´still doesn't work. Can somebody point me at the right direction or maybe just say what the problem is and i can fix it :D ?

[image: Error code wrong]

Main:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class WebServer {

    private static int PORT = 8888;
    private static String ROOT_DIR = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        if (isCorrect(args) == true) {

            boolean isRunning = true;

            try {

            /* Creates a new server socket */
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();

            /* Binds the port to the server */
                SocketAddress localBindPoint = new InetSocketAddress(PORT);

                serverSocket.bind(localBindPoint);

                System.out.println("==============================================" +
                        "\n| HTTP Web Server |" +
                        "\n===================" +
                        "\n| Configuration: " +
                        "\n| Directory: " +
                        "\n| " + ROOT_DIR +
                        "\n| Port: " +
                        "\n| " + PORT +
                        "\n| Usage: <directory> <port>" +
                        "\n| ctrl-c to exit" +
                        "\n==============================================");
            /* The server is running */
                while (isRunning) {

                    try {

                /* Accept connection by client */
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                /* Each connected client gets a new thread */
                        new Thread(new RequestHandler(socket, ROOT_DIR)).start();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Address already in use!" +
                        "\nClose running connection or choose other port");
            }
        } else
            usageMsg();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static boolean isDirectory(String path){
        File filePath = null;
        try{

            filePath = new File(path);
            /* False if file is not a directory */
            if (!filePath.isDirectory())
                return false;

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        /* Seems to be a file path */
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isCorrect(String[] args){

        if (args.length != 2){
            usageMsg();
            return false;
        }

        try{
            ROOT_DIR = args[0].toString();
            PORT = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException n){
            System.err.println(n.getMessage());
        }

        if (!isDirectory(ROOT_DIR)){
            usageMsg();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void usageMsg(){
        System.err.println("Invalid arguments"+
                "\nUsage: java -jar Webserver.jar <directory> <port>");
    }
}
```

RequestHandler:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * Web Server Request Handler.
 * Created on 2015-02-16.
 */

public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {

    /*
    TODO ( ) Problem 1
    TODO ( ) Problem 2
    TODO ( ) Problem 3
    TODO (X) Index page for first page.
    TODO (X) Read and download images & other files
    TODO ( ) Fix header responses
    TODO ( ) Error responses
     */

    private String
            OK = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK",
            NOT_FOUND = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found",
            BAD_REQUEST = "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request",
            FORBIDDEN = "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden",
            SERVER_ERROR = "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error";

    private String ROOT_DIR;
    private Socket client;
    private PrintStream send;
    private DataInputStream fromClient;
    private DataOutputStream out;

    RequestHandler(Socket client, String ROOT_DIR) {
        this.client = client;
        this.ROOT_DIR = ROOT_DIR;

        try {
            send = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            fromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Reads the HTTP request and responds */
    public void run() {
        String request = null;
        String fileName = null;
        StringTokenizer tok = null;

        try {

            /* Read HTTP request from client */
            while ((request = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(request);
                tok = new StringTokenizer(request);

            /* Extracts the file path from the GET command */
                if (tok.hasMoreElements() && tok.nextToken().equals("GET")
                        && tok.hasMoreElements()) {

                    fileName = tok.nextToken();
                } else
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();

                /* */
                if (fileName.endsWith("/"))
                    fileName += "index.html";

                /* Illegal characters, prevent access to super directories */
                if (fileName.indexOf("..") >= 0 || fileName.indexOf('|') >= 0
                        || fileName.indexOf(':') >= 0 || fileName.indexOf('~') >= 0) {

                    error(FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden Access", fileName);
                }
                else

                if (new File(fileName).isDirectory()) {
                    fileName = fileName.replace('\\', '/');
                    send.close();
                    return;
                }

            /* File name is ROOT_DIR + file name */
                fileName = ROOT_DIR + fileName;

            /* Create file */
                File file = new File(fileName);

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    fileName = fileName + "index.html";
                }
            /* File does not exist */
                if (file.exists()){
            /* Determines the MIME type of the file */
                    String mimeType = getMimeType(file);

            /* Sends the file */
                    sendFile(file, mimeType, fileName);
                    client.close();
                }
                else
                    error(NOT_FOUND, "404 File Not Found", fileName);
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Sends the requested file to the client */
    public void sendFile(File file, String fileType, String fileName) {
        try {
            // Buffer must not be to low, => fragments
            int length = (int) file.length();
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

            /* Write until bytes is empty */
            while ((length = fileIn.read(bytes)) != -1 ){
                out.write(bytes, 0, length);
                out.flush();
                out.writeBytes(OK);
                out.writeBytes("Server: Jakobs Web Server v1.0");
                out.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileType + "\r\n");
                out.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + length + "\r\n");
                out.writeBytes("");
            }
            send.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Sends the header response to the client */
    public void sendHeaderResponse(String code, String fileType){
        try {
            out.writeBytes(code);
            out.writeBytes("Server: Jakobs Web Server v1.0");
            out.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + fileType + "\r\n");
            out.writeBytes("");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Sends error response to the client */
    public void error(String code, String error, String fileName){
        System.err.println(error +
                "\nFile Requested: " + fileName);

        /* Sends the error code header */
        sendHeaderResponse(code, fileName);

        /* Sends the error message and cause to client */
        send.print("<html><head><title>" + error + "</title></head><body>");
        send.print("<h1>" + error + "</h1>\r\n");
        send.println("Location: /" + fileName + "/\r\n");
        send.println("Exception Cause: " + error + "\r\n");
        send.print("<a href=\"index.html\">Start Page</a>");
        send.print("</body>\"</html>");
        send.flush();
        send.close();
    }

    /* Finds out the MIME type of the requested file */
    public String getMimeType(File f) {
        String file = f.toString();
        String type = "";
        if (file.endsWith(".txt")) {
            type = "text/txt";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".html") || file.endsWith("htm")) {
            type = "text/html";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".jpg")) {
            type = "image/jpg";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".png")) {
            type = "image/png";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
            type = "image/jpeg";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".gif")) {
            type = "image/gif";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            type = "application/pdf";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            type = "audio/mpeg";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".class")){
            type = "application/octet-stream";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".mp4")){
            type = "video/mp4";
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you write e.g. `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` to the client, not just the `400`.

Actually no, your problem is that you don't end the response properly. The browser keeps receiving data and shows no response code received. Let me see how this can be fixed in your code.

Also, you use two wrapper streams around `client.getOutputStream()` to send data to the client (`send` and `out`). Not sure why you do this. This looks weird. You should use just one wrapper stream. And you never close `out`, probably that's your problem, that's why the browser thinks the response is not yet fully received. Try to use one stream and handle it properly.

OK, here is your code fixed.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * Web Server Request Handler.
 * Created on 2015-02-16.
 */

public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {

    /*
    TODO ( ) Problem 1
    TODO ( ) Problem 2
    TODO ( ) Problem 3
    TODO (X) Index page for first page.
    TODO (X) Read and download images & other files
    TODO ( ) Fix header responses
    TODO ( ) Error responses
     */

    private String
            OK = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK",
            NOT_FOUND = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found",
            BAD_REQUEST = "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request",
            FORBIDDEN = "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden",
            SERVER_ERROR = "HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error";

    private String ROOT_DIR;
    private Socket client;
    private PrintStream send;
    private DataInputStream fromClient;
    // private DataOutputStream out;

    RequestHandler(Socket client, String ROOT_DIR) {
        this.client = client;
        this.ROOT_DIR = ROOT_DIR;

        try {
            send = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            fromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            // out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Reads the HTTP request and responds */
    public void run() {
        String request = null;
        String fileName = null;
        StringTokenizer tok = null;

        try {

            /* Read HTTP request from client */
            while ((request = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(request);
                tok = new StringTokenizer(request);

            /* Extracts the file path from the GET command */
                if (tok.hasMoreElements() && tok.nextToken().equals("GET")
                        && tok.hasMoreElements()) {

                    fileName = tok.nextToken();
                } else
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();

                /* */
                if (fileName.endsWith("/"))
                    fileName += "index.html";

                /* Illegal characters, prevent access to super directories */
                if (fileName.indexOf("..") >= 0 || fileName.indexOf('|') >= 0
                        || fileName.indexOf(':') >= 0 || fileName.indexOf('~') >= 0) {

                    error(FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden Access", fileName);
                }
                else

                if (new File(fileName).isDirectory()) {
                    fileName = fileName.replace('\\', '/');
                    send.close();
                    return;
                }

            /* File name is ROOT_DIR + file name */
                fileName = ROOT_DIR + fileName;

            /* Create file */
                File file = new File(fileName);

                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    fileName = fileName + "index.html";
                }
            /* File does not exist */
                if (file.exists()){
            /* Determines the MIME type of the file */
                    String mimeType = getMimeType(file);

            /* Sends the file */
                    sendFile(file, mimeType, fileName);
                    client.close();
                }
                else
                    error(NOT_FOUND, "404 File Not Found", fileName);
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Sends the requested file to the client */
    public void sendFile(File file, String fileType, String fileName) {
        try {
            // Buffer must not be to low, => fragments
            int length = 0; // (int) file.length();
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            /* Write until bytes is empty */
            while ((length = fileIn.read(bytes)) != -1 ){
                bos.write(bytes, 0, length);
                // send.write(bytes, 0, length);
                // send.flush();
            }
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            byte[] data1 = bos.toByteArray();

            System.out.print(new String(data1));
            send.print(OK);
            send.print("");
            send.print("Server: Jakobs Web Server v1.0");
            send.print("Content-Type: " + fileType + "\r\n");
            send.print("Content-Length: " + data1.length + "\r\n");
            send.println("");
            send.write(data1, 0, data1.length);
            send.println("");

            send.flush();
            send.close();

            fileIn.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Sends the header response to the client */
    public void sendHeaderResponse(String code, String fileType){
        try {
            send.print(code);
            send.print("Server: Jakobs Web Server v1.0");
            send.print("Content-Type: " + fileType + "\r\n");
            send.print("");
            send.println();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Sends error response to the client */
    public void error(String code, String error, String fileName){
        System.err.println(error +
                "\nFile Requested: " + fileName);

        /* Sends the error code header */
        sendHeaderResponse(code, fileName);

        // send.println("ERROR");

        /* Sends the error message and cause to client */

        send.print("<html><head><title>" + error + "</title></head><body>");
        send.print("<h1>" + error + "</h1>\r\n");
        send.println("Location: /" + fileName + "/\r\n");
        send.println("Exception Cause: " + error + "\r\n");
        send.print("<a href=\"index.html\">Start Page</a>");
        send.print("</body></html>");

        send.flush();
        send.close();
    }

    /* Finds out the MIME type of the requested file */
    public String getMimeType(File f) {
        String file = f.toString();
        String type = "";
        if (file.endsWith(".txt")) {
            type = "text/txt";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".html") || file.endsWith("htm")) {
            type = "text/html";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".jpg")) {
            type = "image/jpg";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".png")) {
            type = "image/png";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
            type = "image/jpeg";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".gif")) {
            type = "image/gif";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".pdf")) {
            type = "application/pdf";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            type = "audio/mpeg";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".class")){
            type = "application/octet-stream";
        } else if (file.endsWith(".mp4")){
            type = "video/mp4";
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: One more fix is needed.

Comment: Something with the display of html error ? Because if i get an error i get an real ugly page without any html formatting. Also in main page you can se the http response text at the bottom . Something else ? 

http://sv.tinypic.com/r/m8ia3a/8

http://sv.tinypic.com/r/2djazio/8

Comment: No, that's a small problem :) Now sendFile has the same issue, the browser keeps receiving bytes. You have quite a few bugs. I will try to fix them as you got me interested :)

Comment: Hm okey. When i try to get a 404 error, now it downloads a textile with the error code in instead of showing it on the page. Sure be my guest.

Comment: OK, it's fixed now. I did several small but important fixes. Compare with your original version.

Comment: Ahaa cool :D Works super nicely now, i see that the most of the problem were with the sendFile() and error response. Streaming a mp3 or video works better now than before also. Before you could only play but not fast forwarding, now its possible. Thx. Will go through it again. Have a nice weekend.